# Override views from Rails Engine using different file extensions (.slim, .haml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, slim-lang

Is there a way to override views from a Rails Engine, but instead of using the same file extension .erb (in my case) use .slim or .haml instead. I can only make it work if I use the same file extension.

Does anyone had this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you want to use different ext with out changing original content? is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, pretty obvious actually, you need to have at least the 'slim' or 'slim-rails' gem in your Gemfile!